# how to get sql dump of a database created in sqlite using sqlalchemy

Tags: python, mysql, sqlite, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

I have data read from json and fed into an sqlite database with proper schema using sql-alchemy in python. (used pd.dataframe.to_sql() for this). I want the database dump (.sql file) of this database.
is there any api in sql alchemy that would do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming that you have a SQLAlchemy `engine` object associated with your SQLite database you can simply use Python's [iterdump](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sqlite3.html#sqlite3.Connection.iterdump) method like so:

```python
con = engine.raw_connection()
with open('C:/Users/Gord/Desktop/dump.sql', 'w') as f:
    for line in con.iterdump():
        f.write('%s\n' % line)
```

Comment: The `iterdump` referenced here is an sqlite3 function.

Comment: Is there any agnostic SQL alchemy function to generate a SQL dump from a database connection?